Why is my polars slower than pandas in simple column divisions?
I have the following test code with time measures:
import time
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 10_000_000
np_arrs = {"x": np.random.rand(n), "y": np.random.rand(n)}
pl_df = pl.DataFrame(np_arrs)
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(np_arrs)

t0 = time.time()
z = np_arrs["x"] / np_arrs["y"]
t1 = time.time()
print(f"time cost: {round((t1 - t0) * 1000)} ms")  # 20 ms

t0 = time.time()
z = pl_df["x"] / pl_df["y"]
t1 = time.time()
print(f"time cost: {round((t1 - t0) * 1000)} ms")  # 42 ms

t0 = time.time()
z = pd_df["x"] / pd_df["y"]
t1 = time.time()
print(f"time cost: {round((t1 - t0) * 1000)} ms")  # 18 ms

It's bizarre to me that polars is about 2x slow. Does anyone know why?
My test environments:

computer: MBP 2020, 13inch, 2GHz 4-core i5, 16GB mem
python: 3.12.3
numpy: 1.26.4
pandas: 2.2.2
polars: 0.20.31


Why is it bizzare?

On my hardware, all three timings are very similar (with np < pl < pd). Polars is not as mature as NumPy (it still hasn't reached a 1.0 release), so we can't expect it to perform well across the board. Pandas uses NumPy under the hood. (side note: use time.perf_counter for benchmarking)

With this code, I get polars and pandas to be almost the same time, but numpy 2x faster.

How does z = pl_df.lazy().select(pl.col.x / pl.col.y).collect(streaming=True) compare?

On my machine, in repeated experiments with more data all three solutions perform  on par.

@jqurious z = pl_df.lazy().select(pl.col.x / pl.col.y).collect(streaming=True) is indeed faster. This expression costs about 20ms which is on par with the other two now on my machine. I also noticed that, without streaming=True it'll be the same old 40ms~50ms. Why?

I don't know the technical details of why, just that Polars has an "in-memory" engine and a "streaming engine". In my testing, some operations are faster on the streaming engine (some are slower). You may consider opening a Github issue to get a response from the devs (they do answer questions on here but not everything gets noticed). (As an example: the streaming engine is currently being rewritten (new_streaming=True) which will enable vertical parallelism for string operations: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17235#issuecomment-2194491978)

@jqurious thank you for your replies. I'll ask on Github.
